# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

The log error is as follows

```
015-07-03 17:37:47.392 CoreData_Saha[4403:133938] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "jgh-55-9I5-view-Ywb-7c-HKv" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab4ff35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a43fbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab4fe6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010b21e415 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 249
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010b0617f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010b061c8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b099d3b -[UINavigationController preferredContentSize] + 149
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b041ec2 -[UIPresentationController preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:] + 101
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b03fb0d __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 108
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010af5f331 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010af5f1ab _afterCACommitHandler + 516
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa84dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa84d20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa7ab53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa7a486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e11e9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010af3c420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    17  CoreData_Saha                       0x0000000109f0de73 main + 115
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d0df145 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Have you tried with "@interface SampleViewController" : UITableViewController to @interface SampleViewController : UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

"[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "jgh-55-9I5-view-Ywb-7c-HKv" nib but didn't get a UITableView."

This is saying that somewhere in your storyboard there's a `UITableViewController` or a subclass of it which has its `view` property connected to something that is not a `UITableView` or subclass of that.

Check each view controller in the storyboard to make sure its view is connected to something appropriate.